# Camel - how to force splitter stop on exception and return aggregated result together with exception

Tags: apache-camel

How to implement such process with camel:

- split
- process each splitted item
- aggregate results

  if exception occurs:
- stop splitting
- return aggregation result of all items before exception together with exception information

Defining .stopOnException() on split, I can achieve stopping the process and outputting exception information without aggregated result.

Is it possible by handling exception inside Aggregation Strategy force splitter to stop processing all remaining items?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the Split exchanges getting stoped upon exception.

in camel 2.2, your Sub exchanges will get processed and if there is any exception further messages will also be processod and in the Aggregation you can look/analyse on this.

```
.stopOnExceptions(false)
```

Camel 2.2: Whether or not to stop continue processing immediately when an
exception occurred. If disable, then Camel continue splitting and process the
sub-messages regardless if one of them failed. You can deal with exceptions in
the AggregationStrategy class where you have full control how to handle that.